# How to deploy my existing NodeJS application in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-cloud-platform

I have developed a web application using Node.js and MongoDB, now am trying to host my existing completed application in Google Cloud Platform.but there is no resource about deploying existing node mongodb web application unless new node application from github.

I need to know how to deploy my existing project.

Help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you want to allocate VMs and than deploy your application and DB there?

Comment: I found a good tutorial you can check https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/tutorial-app

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google App Engine to run NodeJS applications in a very straightforward way.

First you need to create a GAE project.
Then you need to have the Google Cloud SDK installed on your machine.
You project should have an app.yaml file that includes the following lines:

```
runtime: nodejs
vm: true
```

You can specify the node version to use in your package.json using:

```
"engines": {
    "node": ">=0.12.7"
}
```

When you are ready to deploy to GAE use the following cmd:

```
$ gcloud preview app deploy
```

You can see an example here for more info:
https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/hello-world

Answer (score 0):

For a Node app interfacing with MongoDB, there is a tutorial @ [Run MongoDB on Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/resources/databases/mongodb). Mongo has to be hosted elsewhere, not in Google Cloud. I selected mLab @ [mLab Mongo](https://mlab.com/). I think this is a good start.

Be careful to not get billed after you're done with the project tutorial. I stopped the App Version, stopping the Node server from running.